# Compile error in toMap() function of Stream on array of PropertyDescriptors

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have following code:

```
    PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Mailingadresse.class).getPropertyDescriptors();
    Map<String, PropertyDescriptor> m = Arrays
        .stream(propertyDescriptors)
        .filter(pd -> pd.getReadMethod() != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(pd -> pd.getName().toLowerCase(), Function::identity));
```

Eclipse shows

> The method toMap(Function, Function) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments
>   (( pd) -> {}, Function::identity)

Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

`Function.identity()` returns a functional interface (`Function`), so you don't need a method reference, you need to call the method:

```
PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Mailingadresse.class).getPropertyDescriptors();
Map<String, PropertyDescriptor> m = Arrays
    .stream(propertyDescriptors)
    .filter(pd -> pd.getReadMethod() != null)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(pd -> pd.getName().toLowerCase(), Function.identity()));
```